# Why are the two bootstrap toggle buttons causing issue?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I have two bootstrap toggle buttons, but when I click one of them, the other is getting affected. Can you please tell me what is wrong in my code ?

```
 <div class="row p-0 m-0">
              <!-- all day event toggle -->
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="allDayEvent">All Day Event:</label><br>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" id="AllDayEventButton" data-toggle="buttons" disable="false">
                                <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="allDayEventYesLbl" >
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="allDayEventYes" autocomplete="off">
                                Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn btn-secondary active " id="allDayEventNoLbl" >
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="allDayEventNo" autocomplete="off">
                                No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                </div>
            <!-- all day event toggle END -->

            <!-- Recurring event toggle -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="recurringEvent">Recurring Event:</label><br>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" id="RecurringButton" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="recurringEventYesLbl">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" value="Y" id="recurringYes" autocomplete="off">
                        Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary active" id="recurringEventNoLbl">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" value="N" id="recurringNo" autocomplete="off" checked>
                        No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- recurring event toggle END -->
             </div>
```

Comment: Probably because they all share the same attribute name `options`?

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple mistake you might have overlooked. Both the inputs in both radio buttons have the same name. Inputs in same radio button should have same name, but in different groups should have different names. Just changing the names in the second group will fix it. Here is a fixed version!

```html
 <div class="row p-0 m-0">
              <!-- all day event toggle -->
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="allDayEvent">All Day Event:</label><br>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" id="AllDayEventButton" data-toggle="buttons" disable="false">
                                <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="allDayEventYesLbl" >
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="allDayEventYes" autocomplete="off">
                                Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn btn-secondary active " id="allDayEventNoLbl" >
                                <input type="radio" name="options" id="allDayEventNo" autocomplete="off">
                                No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                </div>
            <!-- all day event toggle END -->

            <!-- Recurring event toggle -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="recurringEvent">Recurring Event:</label><br>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" id="RecurringButton" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="recurringEventYesLbl">
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsTwo" value="Y" id="recurringYes" autocomplete="off">
                        Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary active" id="recurringEventNoLbl">
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsTwo" value="N" id="recurringNo" autocomplete="off" checked>
                        No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- recurring event toggle END -->
             </div>
```